# Разбор слова по составу *шитье*

Tags: состав-слова

Прошу помочь мне разобраться со словом  *шитье* (и ему подобными). Выделите корень слова, окончание, возможные суффиксы.
Побалуйте меня корректными ссылками, если это возможно.
Для затравки, разбор слова по Викисловарю :

> Корень: -ши-; суффикс: -ть; окончание: -ё

Такой разбор слова я принять не могу. Каким образом в существительном присутствует глагольный суффикс *-ть*? Не может быть!

Дополнительный недоуменный вопросище : что, наша отечественная филологическая наука **не доросла еще** до академического нормообразующего всем-даже-тебе-доступного сетевого Словаря морфемного состава слов?
Может, объявить грант на составление такого словаря.
Как можно мучить школьников и студентов (?) тем, чего не существует в научном российском пространстве.
Заранее благодарен за возможные умные ответы.

Comment: Хотелось бы заслушать Ивана Стрельцова по этому вопросу - автора непротиворечивой теории русского языка.

Comment: это ирония?

Comment: Горькая, надо признать...

Comment: А какой суффикс в слове "ружьё"?

Comment: Давайте посмотрим в словаре Тихонова : *ружj-о*. Корень и окончание. Хотя свободно можно выделить суффикс **-j-**  и корень **руж**. Прилагательное : ружный, глагол : ружити. Является ли сей казус профессиональным упущением словариста? А может, Тихонов решил упростить ситуацию. Зачем в ружье - суффикс?? Ведь он считает это слово непроизводным, в чем можно справедливо усомниться.

Comment: Ваше высказывание "шить-ё = шитьё" аналогично высказыванию "2! x 3 = 6".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Почему ж не доросла? Таких словарей много. Вот передо мной Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь Панова и Текучёва (есть во всех книжных магазинах),вот Школьный словарь строения слов русского языка З.А.Потихи.
Вот словари-онлайн:
http://samlib.ru/k/krukower_w/slovoobraz_kr.shtml :   ши-тj-о' [шитьё]

В словаре Тихонова на Яндексе: Шитьё-Ши/ть/ё [й/о́]
    http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/~%D0%A8%D0%B8/5/

Эти словари говорят о том, что  в слове ШИТЬЁ суффикс -ть[j]-.Звук -j- может быть скрыт в орфографической записи. Например, в слове вязание выделяется суффикс -ниj-, а в слове братья – словоизменительный суффикс -j-, образующий форму множественного числа, в слове враньё суфф.-нь[j]-В Викисловаре даётся только буквенная запись состава слова, этого хватает для младших школьников.В старших классах сейчас требуется частичное отображение состава фонетического, звукового, чтобы показать звуковой состав  йотированных букв: Ё=[jo]. Так что это не суффикс инфинитива -ть-, а суффикс -тьj-суффикс собирательности и вещественности, а также признак образования отглагольных сущ. ( сущ. по действию шить)

Comment: Слов типа *шитье* в русском языке всего двадцать от силы. Смотрим пример :  
>Колотье  
Корень: -кол- ; суффикс: -отʲ ; окончание: -ё . (Вики)))))))

>Так что это не суффикс
инфинитива -ть-, а **суффикс -тьj-суффикс
собирательности и вещественности,** а также
признак образования отглагольных сущ. ( сущ.
по действию шить)

Мне все это кажется набором псевдонаучных слов. Суффикс -тьj является обычной выдумкой кабинетных обитателей. Вот есть такое слово : **шитик** (судно, шитое из досок). В нем тоже, кроме уменьшительного суффикса -ик, найдутся какие-то невероятные сущности?

Comment: Это Вы своё мнение, простите, дилетанта собираетесь выдать за научную истину, не удосужась внимательно посмотреть даже в Вики, а я вот увидела j в вашем комментарии. Посмотрите, что там вверху маленькой буквой - не j?  http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%91
колотьё- суфф. -от[j]- так в Вики. ,а в слове ШИТИК нет йотированных букв. Вы об этом тоже впервые слышите? Сильно же Вы отстали. Я=[ja],Е=[jэ], ю=[j у],ё =[jо].Теперь это даже в начальной школе учат.

Comment: колот[jo],колот[ja],колот[jу]-что меняется?-о,а,у - это окончание, а j остаётся неизменным, входит в суффикс. Но в чисто буквенной записи получается кол/оть/ё, ши/ть/ё. Всё верно.

Comment: для этого и нужна транскрипция

Comment: Как бы ученые разбирали слова по частям, если бы не было букв - и русских, и латинских? Суффикс **-тьj**, страшно подумать, не родился бы на свет.

Comment: Не было бы букв-не было бы письменного языка и разбирать слова не было бы необходимости. Слава богу, они есть и есть наука словообразование и морфемика, и она совершенствуется. А в словари, действительно, смотреть надо почаще, трудных случаев много.

Comment: По поводу словарей и ссылок. Бумажная литература никому сейчас, а тем более завтра, **не нужна**. Словарь В.Круковера неполный, любительский, крайне плохо оформленный. Нет, не доросла российская филнаука до простого и полного словаря по морфологическому составу слов. Все слова по алфавиту с разбивкой каждого слова на морфемы, без всякой латинницы и прочих вывертов. Вот как пишется русскими буковками - так его и разбери по составу. Не можешь, наука, так и скажи : не могем-с...